# Intellij IDEA crashes when trying to compile/run a program

Tags: intellij-idea, windows-7, crash

I wanted to try out IDEA because I kinda want to move away from Eclipse. However, everytime I try to build or run code from inside IDEA, it just crashes with no error message. The only information I get is from Windows itself:

```
Problemsignatur (Problem signature):
  Problemereignisname (Problem event name): BEX
  Anwendungsname (Application name):    idea.exe
  Anwendungsversion (Application version):  14.0.3.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel (Application timestamp):    5437b4c8
  Fehlermodulname (Error module name):  SDHook32.dll
  Fehlermodulversion (Error module version):    2.3.39.2
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel (Error module timestamp):  535a5137
  Ausnahmeoffset (Exception offset):    00025942
  Ausnahmecode (Exception code):    c0000417
  Ausnahmedaten (Exception data):   00000000
  Betriebsystemversion (Operating system version):  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Gebietsschema-ID (Area schema ID):    3079
  Zusatzinformation 1 (Additional information 1):   6ec5
  Zusatzinformation 2 (Additional information 2):   6ec5ee19c106a54dd0feced4a6ea5c17
  Zusatzinformation 3 (Additional information 3):   633b
  Zusatzinformation 4 (Additional information 4):   633bad3421e95a8b92bd60a69d1ca25c
```

Sorry that it is in German, I tried to translate the keys into English but don't know if they actually match the English version of the error message. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, error happens with both 32-bit and 64-bit version of IDEA. Used JDK is 1.8.0_20 (also 64-bit).

Can't seem to find anything about this on Google, maybe one of you knows how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash happens in a DLL which is part of [this application](http://www.safer-networking.org/). You may want to uninstall the application if you don't need it.

Comment: This is indeed a Spybot S&D problem. Disabling Spybot's Live Protection did the trick for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a windows issue. It's just that it is happening to you when using IntelliJ IDEA. The key in the error message is the `Problem Event Name: BEX` line. BEX refers to Buffer Overflow Exception. Take a read through the post [Problem Event Name: BEX, error message](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_programs/problem-event-name-bex-error-message/cf5baf73-0877-4070-abfb-a2c3a17a9e10) on Microsoft Answers and the [Data Execution Prevention](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738483%28WS.10%29.aspx) TechNet article referenced in that answer. You can also Google [windows bex crash](https://www.google.com/#q=windows+bex+crash) or a similar term. Most information refers to the need to make a settings change to the "Data Execution Prevention" option. If you continue to have issues, you may want to post as a Windows-7 question on [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the right direction. However, I can't add "idea.exe" (or "idea64.exe") to the list of DEP exclusions, as Windows tells me:
This program must run with data execution protection (DEP) enabled.
You cannot turn off DEP for this program.

I really would like to avoid turning off DEP entirely for my system, so I guess I head over to SuperUser.com for now. Thanks anyways.

Edit: Can't upvote your answer since I don't have enough reputation yet. Sorry